# Taking character into array and printing it in C

Tags: c, for-loop, char, scanf, conversion-specifier

I was interested in the following problem:
Take the colors  as characters (for example : 'y' for yellow, 'r' for red etc.) into an array and display the same. While displaying there should be a single space between each characters. So to do this I wrote following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


 int main(){

char a[10];
int i,n;
printf("Enter the number of colors (less than 10)\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter colors as alphabets : ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    scanf("%c", &a[i]);
}
printf("Entered colors are : ");
for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%c ", a[i]);
}

return 0;
 }
```

If I enter the size of array as 3 and Colors as r y g , the output is not printing all three inputs instead it is printing only one.
Little did I realized that there is a problem with scanf function. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following conversion specifier

```
scanf(" %c", &a[i]);
      ^^^
```

This allows to skip white spaces that for example correspond to the pressed Enter key.

Also after this loop

```
for (i = 0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%c ", a[i]);
}
```

place the statement

```
putchar( '\n' );
```